# Predicates on Join not working

Tags: java, sql, jpa, criteria-api

If I am using a Join to create predicates in a criteriaquery I won't get any results. The same predicates are returning entities when I am using the `Game` table as root.

Working Query:

```
    CriteriaQuery<Game> query = cb.createQuery(Game.class);
    Root<Game> root = query.from(Game.class);

    List<Predicate> predicates = new LinkedList<Predicate>();
    if(!selectedPlatforms.isEmpty()) {
        predicates.add(root.get(Game_.type).in(TypeConverter.convert(selectedPlatforms)));
    }

    if(!selectedCategories.isEmpty()) {
        Join<Game, String> collection = root.join(Game_.categories);
        predicates.add(collection.in(cb.literal(selectedCategories)));
    }

    if(!selectedGames.isEmpty()) {
        predicates.add(cb.isTrue(root.get(Game_.name).in(selectedGames)));
    }


    query.where(cb.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()])));
    games = em.createQuery(query).getResultList();
```

Not working query:

```
    CriteriaQuery<Hit> query = cb.createQuery(Hit.class);
    List<Predicate> predicates = new LinkedList<>();
    Date startDate = null;
    Date endDate = null;

    Root<Hit> hitRoot = query.from(Hit.class);
    switch (time) {
        case "Week":
            startDate = new DateTime().withWeekOfWeekyear(timeValue).withDayOfWeek(DateTimeConstants.MONDAY).toDate();
            endDate = new DateTime().withWeekOfWeekyear(timeValue+1).withDayOfWeek(DateTimeConstants.SUNDAY).toDate();
    }
    predicates.add(cb.and(cb.greaterThanOrEqualTo(hitRoot.<Date>get("hitDate"), startDate), cb.lessThanOrEqualTo(hitRoot.<Date>get("hitDate"), endDate)));

    Join<Hit, Game> gameJoin = hitRoot.join("game", JoinType.LEFT);
    if(!selectedPlatforms.isEmpty()) {
        predicates.add(gameJoin.get(Game_.type).in(TypeConverter.convert(selectedPlatforms)));
    }

    if(!selectedCategories.isEmpty()) {
        Join<Game, String> collection = gameJoin.join(Game_.categories);
        predicates.add(collection.in(cb.literal(selectedCategories)));
    }

    if(!selectedGames.isEmpty()) {
        predicates.add(cb.isTrue(gameJoin.get(Game_.name).in(selectedGames)));
    }

    query.groupBy(hitRoot.get("hitDate"), hitRoot.get("shop"));
    query.orderBy(cb.asc(hitRoot.get("shop")));
    query.where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]));

    List<Hit> results = em.createQuery(query).getResultList();
```

The following part is responsible for not returning any machting entity. The same part just applied to a `Root` instead of `Join` like in the first query is returning machting entites. Without this part everything else is working.

```
    if(!selectedGames.isEmpty()) {
        predicates.add(cb.isTrue(gameJoin.get(Game_.name).in(selectedGames)));
    }
```

Comment: Can you exclude that the cause isn't in JodaTime predicate? Have you tried without it? Add the mappings used in the entity definitions for defining the join relationship

Comment: If I comment out the grouping and the JodaTime predicate the result is still the same.

Comment: What does it mean _not working_ and _the result is still the same_?

Comment: The difference between the two queries is that in the second the `Game` tables was used as a join, but the predicates on this table are still the same. The predicates are getting constructed but there are no entities returned that match these predicates. On the first query there are fitting entities.

Comment: But the second query has additional restrictions: the games must be referenced by a hit, which itself has date restrictions. So, are you sure that the games returned by the first query are linked tohits satisfying those date restrictions?

Answer (score 0):

The problem resolved itself by restarting the application server in 'Run' mode.